# microsoft graph api. automatic login after user is logged out problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, microsoft-graph-api

I have succesfully setup a NodeJS web application that uses the Microsoft Graph API. There is only one silly problem.

So if a user wants to use the application, he has to log in first. Thats why the first page of my app is the authentication url of the Microsoft API. After the user has succesfully logged in, he is send to the homepage. Now when the user clicks on logout button, problems begin to appear.

As I have said earlier, the first page of the app is the auth url from Microsoft API. When the user logs out he is send back to that same url, because he is not logged in anymore. While he is being send to the login url, microsoft automatically logs the user back in.

So my question is, is there a way the user isn't logged in autmatically after he signed out?

I know this has to do with the cookies from login.live.com. Because if I delete them I have to mannually sign in again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use prompt parameter. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code).